# Do i need to add app at console for using Google Maps Intents?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Below code i am using to open a location in google maps from my app.

```
   Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", Float.valueOf(latitude), Float.valueOf(longitude)));
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(mContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
```

The above code works fine even if i have NOT added my app to google console and enabled google maps api.Why its working fine and do i need to add?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have a google maps app on your device which is handling the intent rather than your own app. As you are specifying a package **"com.google.android.apps.maps"** which according to the google map documentation is the google map android app that handles it.
For Reference :
[Google Map Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

So, you do not need to use console and sign your package and use the key, assign by the google.